# setting value in action method

Tags: visualforce, actionfunction, pagereference

Action method is called but Username is null in visualforce

VisualForce page:

```
<apex:page controller="exampleCon">
<apex:form >
  <apex:actionFunction name="sayHello" action="{!sayHello}" rerender="out"/>
</apex:form>

 <apex:outputPanel id="out">
  <apex:outputText>{!username}</apex:outputText> 
  </apex:outputPanel>
  <apex:outputlink onclick="sayHello();" styleClass="btn"> 
    say Hello
  </apex:outputlink>       
</apex:page>
```

Controller:

```
 public class exampleCon {
    String uname;

    public String getUsername() {
        return uname;
    }

    public PageReference sayHello() {
        uname = UserInfo.getName();
        return null;
    }       
 }
```

Comment: Are you sure that sayHello action is being called? I just tested your code and its not

Comment: I have updated the code as per @sfdcfox and action method is called now but username is not displaying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be:

```
<apex:outputlink onclick="sayHello();" styleClass="btn"> 
    say Hello
</apex:outputlink>
```

Note the parenthesis.

Also note you're using multiple forms, which will cause problems with the view state.

I've updated your code such that it works.

```
<apex:page controller="exampleCon">
<apex:form >
  <apex:actionFunction name="sayHello" action="{!sayHello}" rerender="out"/>

 <apex:outputPanel id="out">
  <apex:outputText >{!username}</apex:outputText> 
  </apex:outputPanel>
  <apex:outputlink onclick="sayHello(); return false;" styleClass="btn"> 
    say Hello
  </apex:outputlink>       
  </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

The controller is fine the way it is.

Comment: I updated the code and removed form tag but still not displaying username on visualforce page

Comment: @sf.dev I created a working version for your perusal. Note how the actionfunction resides within the same form as the rerender target-- this is necessary. Also, you do need to return a false value to prevent the default browser action. I neglected to mention this previously.